# Which libraries need to be added in java web application to support ExtJS

Tags: extjs, dojo

We have an application which has UI part in javascript and dojo 1.8.3. Now we have been asked to replace dojo with ExtJS. The server side of application uses struts2 as framework.

I just wanted to know which libraries I need to include in lib folder of web-app so that it support ExtJS. I have include the struts-json-plugin.jar to support json with struts2.

But how to include ExtJS features into the web-application.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot "replace dojo with ExtJS" easily. For us, this required a full rewrite of the web app and a clear distinction between frontend and backend. You would have to start from scratch with an empty ExtJS project and rebuild the whole frontend.

When we went away from Dojo, without having prior knowledge of "how to do things in ExtJS", it took about 18 months (with a lot trial and error) to get feature parity between the old Dojo frontend and the new ExtJS frontend.

Comment: We have an entire dojo library in our application. So to include ExtJS, what should be added in the application. I agree that we need to write the code differently. But what library or what .js files needs to be added so that ExtJS is available in our application.